# Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects in angular 14

Tags: typescript, angular14upgrade

I have updated angular v10 to v13. Migration is completed without any error but while I'm trying to run ng serve command, I'm getting this compile time error.

tsconfig.ts:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,    
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es5",    
    "newLine": "LF",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "rxjs": ["node_modules/rxjs", "node_modules/rxjs"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

Error:
**Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.**
**if (!(0, fs_1.existsSync)(startPath)) {**

I tried to make changed in tsconfig by replacing es5 to es6 and es2016 but that dind't work for me.
If anyone knows how to resolve this error, that will be helpful for me.

Comment: Post your error message as text instead of image

Comment: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side 
effects. if (!(0, fs_1.existsSync)(startPath)) {

Comment: Edit your question to replace the image link with the text, not in comment.

Comment: Edited description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48163), fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51989).
The PR is merged in typescript [v5.1.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v5.1.5).

According to [Angular version compatibility](https://angular.io/guide/versions#actively-supported-versions), you have to upgrade to Angular v16.1.x in order to be able to use typescript >= v5.1.5

Comment: I am using sitecore-Jss in my project and sitecore-Jss only support till angular 14